# How to resolve this "ClassNotFoundException" error

Tags: java, log4j, classnotfoundexception, classnotfound

Hi I am getting this error

**Error: Could not find or load main class Log4jEx.BasicConfiguratorEx
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Log4jEx.BasicConfiguratorEx**

This is my program

```
package Log4jEx;

import org.apache.log4j.BasicConfigurator;
import org.apache.log4j.Logger;

public class BasicConfiguratorEx {

    static Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(BasicConfiguratorEx.class); 
    //Creating object for Logger without NEW//

    public static void main(String[] args) {            
        BasicConfigurator.configure();
        logger.debug("This is a debug");
        logger.info("This is a info");
        logger.warn("This is a warn");
        logger.fatal("This is a fatal message");    
    }    
}
```

Comment: `java !== javascript`

Comment: By adding that class to the classpath

Comment: Where and when do you get this error? In your IDE, during compiling, during startup?

Comment: @WesleyDeKeirsmaeker During compiling

Answer (score 0):

**log4j 1.x**

BasicConfigurator is a log4j 1.2 class and cannot be used to configure Log4j 2.

> Log4j 1.x had reached end of life

If you want to use BasicConfigurator in your project.

1. download log4j 1.2 jar from this [website](http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/download.html).
2. Add log4j-1.2.17 to your project build path as external jar files.

**log4j 2.x**

No need BasicConfigurator class.

```
import org.apache.logging.log4j.LogManager;
import org.apache.logging.log4j.Logger;

public class HelloWorld {
    private static final Logger logger = LogManager.getLogger("HelloWorld");
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        logger.debug("This is debug message");
        logger.info("This is info message");
        logger.warn("This is warn message");
        logger.fatal("This is fatal message");
        logger.error("This is error message");
        System.out.println("Executed successfully....");

    }
}

output:
This is debug message
This is info message
This is warn message
This is fatal message
This is error message
Logic executed successfully....
```

add log4j2.properties file under src/main/resources

```
name=PropertiesConfig

rootLogger.level=debug
rootLogger.appenderRefs=stdout
rootLogger.appenderRef.stdout.ref=StandardOutput

appenders=console

#log messages to terminal
appender.console.type=Console
appender.console.name=StandardOutput
```

in pom.xml add the below dependency

```
<dependency>
   <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
   <artifactId>log4j-api</artifactId>
   <version>2.13.1</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
   <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
   <artifactId>log4j-core</artifactId>
   <version>2.13.1</version>
</dependency>
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: @SarathKumar i have updated the solution. I hope it should work. If not, let me know.

Comment: @SarathKumar now you can use log4j 1.x with BasicConfiguratorEx  or lo4j 2.x in your project.